# Laravel authentication bug?

Tags: php, laravel, web, migration, laravel-blade

I had a problem, I spent 2 hours solving it, but I can't understand it. Why is this happening?

I have built-in LoginController. It uses "use AuthenticatesUsers". And there is a "attemptLogin" method inside it:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

If I remove `$request->filled('remember')`, everything works for me. Could you explain why this is happening, please?

**view**

```
   <div class="auth"> <!-- Authorization window -->
                <div class="auth__title">Authorization</div>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <input name='username' type="text">
                    <p>Password</p>
                    <input name='password' type="text">
                    <a class="auth__forget-link" href="#">Forgot?</a>
                    <button class="auth__submit button" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </form>
    </div>  <!-- Authorization window -->
```

**model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username','password','name','email','position'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password','remember_token',
    ];

    public function projects() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project','user_id');
    }

}
```

**migration**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('fio');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('api_token')->nullable();
        $table->string('position')->nullable();
        $table->enum('role', ['admin', 'supervisor']);
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
```

P.S. Sorry for the trouble with the model code, I don't know how to insert this correctly

Comment: what's the error / problem?

Comment: @GiovanniS It just doesn't log in.
I tried to do "dd($request->failed('remember'))" and kept getting "false"

Comment: doesn't look like your form is passing ```remember```

Comment: @GiovanniS
If I want to use the initial method "attempt Login", I need to insert the field ""<input class="form-registration-login" type="checkbox" name="remember" ID="remember">""?
I read the documentation, but I didn't understand why this field is needed. You are an experienced person, could you share why this is necessary?

Comment: " It just doesn't log in.", may i know what would happen if successfully logged in?

Comment: @davidvalentino After authorization, I have content divided by roles (admin or simple user), which I specify using if Auth::user()
If you are an experienced Laravel developer, it would be cool if you would help me (or at least answer my questions), I'm just a beginner and Laravel is somehow difficult for me.